# Url could not be found in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have an ajax call as follows:

```
function getBodyHeights(seats_id) {
    $('[data-body-length]').html(gettext("Body length"));
    $('[data-weights]').html(gettext("Weights"));
    $('[data-wheel-drive]').html(gettext("Wheel drive"));
    $('[data-transmission]').html(gettext("Transmission"));
    $('[data-trim]').html(gettext("Trim Level"));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/master/heights/' + seats_id,
        success: function (data) {
            removeActiveClass();
            $('#content').html(data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $('#body-heights-error').removeClass('hidden').html(error.responseText)
        }
    })
}
```

In root folder I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ....
   url(r'^master/', include('master.urls')),
   ...
]
```

In the master folder in urls.py I have it as follows

```
urlpatterns = [
   ....
   url(r'^facelifts/(\d+)/$', views_data.facelifts, name='facelifts'),
   url(r'^seats/(\d+)/$', views_data.seats, name='seats'),
   url(r'^heights/(\d+)/$', views_data.body_heights, name='heights'),
   ...
]
```

But when I try to execute the ajax call on click i get an error:

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
function getFacelifts(body_id) {
    $('[data-seats]').html(gettext("Seats"));
    $('[data-body-height]').html(gettext("Body height"));
    $('[data-body-length]').html(gettext("Body length"));
    $('[data-weights]').html(gettext("Weights"));
    $('[data-engine]').html(gettext("Engine"));
    $('[data-wheel-drive]').html(gettext("Wheel drive"));
    $('[data-transmission]').html(gettext("Transmission"));
    $('[data-trim]').html(gettext("Trim Level"));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/master/facelifts/' + body_id,
        success: function (data) {
            removeActiveClass();
            $('#content').html(data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $('#facelifts-error').removeClass('hidden').html(error.responseText)
        }
    })
}

function getSeats(facelift_id) {
    $('[data-body-height]').html(gettext("Body height"));
    $('[data-body-length]').html(gettext("Body length"));
    $('[data-weights]').html(gettext("Weights"));
    $('[data-engine]').html(gettext("Engine"));
    $('[data-wheel-drive]').html(gettext("Wheel drive"));
    $('[data-transmission]').html(gettext("Transmission"));
    $('[data-trim]').html(gettext("Trim Level"));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/master/seats/' + facelift_id,
        success: function (data) {
            removeActiveClass();
            $('#content').html(data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $('#seats-error').removeClass('hidden').html(error.responseText)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you have __init__.py file in directory "master"?

Comment: which version of django you are using ?

Comment: Check the update. I have almost the same functions for facelifts and seats and those two are working without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem, try change this:

```
url: '/master/heights/' + seats_id,
```

for this:

```
url: '/master/heights/' + seats_id + '/',
```

Ajax to django is so strict